# When was Khemet renamed to Misr?

Tags: ancient-egypt

Egypt was called Khemet in the early period (Old Kingdom) and later Misr (a name that remains even today) but I am wondering when they changed the name from Khemet to Misr, what century would be considered a good precision answer, if possible.

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify where you've searched and what you found already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help] and, in particular, [ask].

Answer (score 12):

The ancient Egyptians thought of their country as two parts: kmt or "Khemet" (meaning "The Black Land" - a reference to the fertile strip along the Nile), and dšrt or "Deshret" (meaning "The Red Land" - referring to the deserts beyond that fertile strip). As you say, they referred to themselves as Kmtyw or "The people of the Black Land" from at least the Old Kingdom (and possibly earlier).

[kmt / dšrt  / Kmtyw  are transliterations from the hieroglyphs. As with some other languages in antiquity, the written forms of the ancient Egyptian language did not include vowels, so transliterations are often written with added letters (often the letter "e") to aid pronunciation]

Even as late as the Persian occupation of Egypt from 525BC to 332BC, the name kmt or "Khemet" is used for the name of Egypt on [statuary](http://www.livius.org/articles/place/susa/susa-photos/susa-statue-of-darius/?) and hieroglyphic inscriptions.

Throughout the Graeco-Roman period kmt was still used as the name for Egypt in hieroglyphic inscriptions (it [appears 3 times on the Rosetta Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Km_(hieroglyph)), dated to 198BC), while the Greek name, Aegyptos, tended to appear in Greek and Latin texts.

---

Misr is the Arabic name for Egypt, and so it's use *by Egyptians* as the name for Egypt probably dates to the Arab conquest of Egypt in the mid 7th century (~640AD). There are [several theories for the origin of Misr as the Arabic name for Egypt](http://egyptianchronicles.blogspot.co.uk/2004/12/origin-of-name-of-egypt.html).

Comment: [Wikipedia: Mizraim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizraim) mentions that "in the Amarna tablets [Egypt] is called Misri", and those [tablets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amarna_letters) are dated to the 14th century BCE, some two thousand years earlier.

Comment: The [Amarna tablets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amarna_letters) are written in written in Akkadian cuneiform and actually use the term "Misri" - the name for Egypt in Canaan and Amurru.  Other, broadly contemporary, regional languages have similar names for Egypt. Ugaritic inscriptions in Syria refer to Egypt as "Msrm", and Assyrian records refer to Egypt as "Mu-ṣur". I suspect that these probably all stem from the same linguistic root as the later Arabic "Misr".

Comment: Not only ancient languages omit vowels; anything with an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjad does.

Comment: @AaronBrick Yes, you are right of course.  I was just trying to explain why "kmt" and "khemet", for example, are equivalent terms in this case.

Comment: Note Misr (or in fact Mitzr as it would be correctly transliterated from Arabic) is most likely a derivative of the _biblical_ Mitzraim, the name of Egypt in Hebrew from the book of Genesis to this very day. No doubt the Hebrew name has further etymological roots to explore.

Comment: The Hebrew word is unique and no other known source apparently uses it, so its origins are unknown as far as I can tell. Also, the more accurate Arabic transliteration would apparently be Matzr.

Comment: According to wp, the arabic name of Egypt is مِصر‎ , i.e. m-ṣ-r. The pronunciation of the middle letter ص is explained e.g. [here](https://www.learnarabiconline.com/arabic-alphabet/12-letters-saad-daad/) and is somewhat similar to an English "s" as in “sound".

Comment: @Boaz A fair guess might be that it's related to another meaning of that Hebrew root, "narrow" or "strait," referring to the relatively narrow Nile valley (by comparison with the rest of the country).

Comment: @sempaiscuba To underscore your point, since Akkadian is a Semitic language, it wouldn't be surprising that another Semitic language like Arabic would have a similar name for Egypt.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your question into google; the second result gave me the answer.

> Then from 525 BCE non-African rulers controlled Kemet, which became known as Egypt under the Macedonians and Ptolemaic rulers. Then in 642 CE Egypt became the Arabic Misr. [*Kemetexpert*](http://kemetexpert.com/egypt-versus-kemet-a-case-of-cognitive-dissonance/)